# Create basic AWS CloufFormation Template for single server

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have no experience with AWS CloudFormation Templates so I apologize for the incredibly simple question which I can't find an answer to because I think it is so basic.

I am trying to create a cloudformation template for a single server in AWS Test Drive. Here is the criteria:

- Deploy AMI
- Force m3-large (no other sizes available)
- Will be running in a single location (no other location available)
- Utilize existing security group
- Get a public IP Spit back the public DNS or public IP address

Everything I've looked up wants to be more complex than I think I need and I can't figure out which pieces are needed and which ones can be taken out. What is the bare minimum to deploy a single ami with no customization (all customization is performed inside the VM during bootup. There should also be no options for other data center locations or other sizes. All templates I've seen have a bunch of options for multiple data centers and multiple sizes and sets up a security group.

I appreciate the links to the AWS site however I have already been there and this is one of the templates that has too much info and I don't know what I can change\exclude.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In case you cannot get this working, the TestDrive page at http://aws.amazon.com/partners/testdrive/ has an email link that will contact the AWS TestDrive team. If you're basically doing what very other TestDrive user has to do then maybe they can just send you a skeleton template (and put it on their web page for future users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon Web Services documentation includes a single-server CloudFormation template that simply creates a Linux EC2 instance and accompanying security group. This one is based in US West 2 (Oregon), but does not appear to be region-specific and should work in any region.

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-west-2/EC2InstanceWithSecurityGroupSample.template

This sample can be found along with others here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/sample-templates-services-us-west-2.html

Comment: i appreciate the answer. I will not have time to check it out for a couple days.